# Powershell to upload files to SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, file-upload

I am trying to upload files to SharePoint Online using Powershell (created with help from online blogs) and I am somewhat successful too. The script uploads files and folders from local drive to SPO.

However there is one feature which I need help with.

The script is able to upload file from local drive to SPO but I do not want to re-upload the same file if it has not changed. Basically the script should upload file/folder to SPO only if it is new or modified. How can I achieve this?

It would be ideal if this script can mirror my local drive to SPO.

Note: I do not want to use OneDrive for Business since it has sync limitation of 5K items. Also cannot use WebDAV approach since the mapped drive keeps disconnecting for some reason.

**Powershell Script**

```
#The following PS script could be used for uploading files into Document Library in SharePoint Online.

Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"


Function Ensure-Folder()
{
Param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
  [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Web]$Web,

  [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
  [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Folder]$ParentFolder, 

  [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
  [String]$FolderUrl

)
    $folderUrls = $FolderUrl.Trim().Split("/",[System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)
    $folderUrl = $folderUrls[0]
    $curFolder = $ParentFolder.Folders.Add($folderUrl)
    $Web.Context.Load($curFolder)
    $web.Context.ExecuteQuery()

    if ($folderUrls.Length -gt 1)
    {
        $curFolderUrl = [System.String]::Join("/", $folderUrls, 1, $folderUrls.Length - 1)
        Ensure-Folder -Web $Web -ParentFolder $curFolder -FolderUrl $curFolderUrl
    }
}



Function Upload-File() 
{
Param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
  [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Web]$Web,

  [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
  [String]$FolderRelativeUrl, 

  [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
  [System.IO.FileInfo]$LocalFile

)

    try {
       $fileUrl = $FolderRelativeUrl + "/" + $LocalFile.Name
       [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File]::SaveBinaryDirect($Web.Context, $fileUrl, $LocalFile.OpenRead(), $true)
    }
    finally {
    #  $fileStream.Close()
    }
}




function Upload-Files()
{

Param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
  [String]$Url,

  [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
  [String]$UserName,

  [Parameter(Mandatory=$False)]
  [String]$Password, 

  [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
  [String]$TargetListTitle,

  [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
  [String]$SourceFolderPath

)

    if($Password) {
       $SecurePassword = $Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
    }
    else {
      $SecurePassword = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the password" -AsSecureString
    }
    $Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($Url)
    $Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($UserName,$SecurePassword)
    $Context.Credentials = $Credentials


    $web = $Context.Web 
    $Context.Load($web)
    $list = $web.Lists.GetByTitle($TargetListTitle);
    $Context.Load($list.RootFolder)
    $Context.ExecuteQuery()


    Get-ChildItem $SourceFolderPath -Recurse | % {
       if ($_.PSIsContainer -eq $True) {
          $folderUrl = $_.FullName.Replace($SourceFolderPath,"").Replace("\","/")   
          if($folderUrl) {
             Ensure-Folder -Web $web -ParentFolder $list.RootFolder -FolderUrl $folderUrl
          }  
       }
       else{
          $folderRelativeUrl = $list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl + $_.DirectoryName.Replace($SourceFolderPath,"").Replace("\","/")  
          Upload-File -Web $web -FolderRelativeUrl $folderRelativeUrl -LocalFile $_ 
       }
    }
}


#Usage


$Url = "https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite"
$UserName = "user@mycompany.com"
$Password = "password1"
$TargetListTitle = "Documents"
#$SourceFolderPath = "C:\LocalFolder"

#Upload files
Upload-Files -Url $Url -UserName $UserName -Password $Password -TargetListTitle $TargetListTitle -SourceFolderPath $SourceFolderPath
```

Comment: There is a new OneDrive for Business client on the horizon that addressed the 5k limit, https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2933738,  and there are documented fixes and resolutions for WebDav mapped drives to Office 365, https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2616712.

Comment: What documented fixes do you have for the dissappearing maped WebDav drives?